# Excel VBA: How to return a given cell's column number

Tags: excel, vba, function

In Excel VBA I am trying to put together a Sub to grab a row of file names to be copied from one location to another with their given cell's column number as a prefix to the file name so that they appear in the new folder in the same order as they are in their row in Excel.
So far I have everything working great, except the part which adds the column number prefix to the filename. Currently in that part of the code I have cellname.Column, which doesn't work.

I'm brand new to VBA, so I've tried copying and pasting bits of code from all over Stack Overflow and other sites to make this work, but nothing is doing the trick yet.

```
Sub copyfiles()

    Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
    Dim xSFileDlg As FileDialog, xDFileDlg As FileDialog
    Dim xSPathStr As Variant, xDPathStr As Variant
    Dim xVal As String

    On Error Resume Next

    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the file names:", "KuTools For Excel", ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Set xSFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xSFileDlg.Title = "Please select the original folder:"
    If xSFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    xSPathStr = xSFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"

    Set xDFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xDFileDlg.Title = "Please select the destination folder:"
    If xDFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    xDPathStr = xDFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"

    For Each xCell In xRg
        xVal = xCell.Value + ".pdf"
        If TypeName(xVal) = "String" And xVal <> "" Then
            FileCopy xSPathStr & xVal, xDPathStr & cellname.Column & xVal
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `xCell.Column`?

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you!